# Allow to add multiple user in people picker field

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, people-picker

My user want to add multiple users in each approval PeoplePicker field. I customized my list using InfoPath. How can I allow multiple users?

NB: I tried using list setting to allow, but I got an error:

> The data types of the following form fields do not match the
>   SharePoint list:  Member to be included  Correlation
>   ID:1d30edd9-654b-477c-b1a2-c69dcf194c57

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your user field in SharePoint list settings to Allow multiple selections: yes

open infopath and let infopath refresh the fields or perform a manual refresh on data/refresh fields menu

then remove your field from the infopath form
(Just from the form, not from the library)

then and drop it again into your form, this will fix any issues with the previous control

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Quick question for you, What about the workflow that I attached ? If I removed it , the workflow gonna get error. What do you think?

Comment: I mean does it affect the workflow or not  when i delete the field in the form?

Comment: Not at all, 
Info path form fields are visualizations of SharePoint fields, by removing a field from the form, you are only removing the ability to edit the fields. as long as you don't remove them from the list it won't affect the workflow

Comment: yet, there can be problems when you modify the field to a multiple user field, as now it will hold more than one value, if you have a lookup to the users field you'll have to change how to retrieve them (normally you'll have the comma separated option)

Comment: When i delete the field in the info path form, it delete from the list at all. I might be wrong

Comment: you should only delete it from the left side (form) , click on the people picker control and hit "delete" on keyboard as it actually doesn't have a "delete" option , then drag and drop it again from the right side (fields menu)

Answer (score 0):

I will present you some example how I managed to make it work

```
public pickersFields: any = [
{
  name: 'Responsible',
  parent: 'ResponsiblePeoplePicker',
  type: 'User',
  multiple: true
},
{
  name: 'Receiver',
  parent: 'ReceiverPeoplePicker',
  type: 'User',
  multiple: false
}
];
```

So, if you want to enable multiple selection, you should use `multiple: true`